# Why do I get +6 for an upvote in my answer, in achievements tab instead of +10

Tags: discussion

I came across a question in Python today: [Reading and printing a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647791/reading-and-printing-a-file-in-c/28647967#28647967)

I was trying out various solution till I came across another solution that seemed to solve the problem.

I had found out another addition that would improve the range of the question, so I added another line of suggestion and posted my own answer.

My answer got upvote, but I saw a +6 instead of +10 in the achievements tab.

I then checked my reputation page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077651/code-frenzy?tab=reputation

but it says +10.

Why then did the achievements tag say +6.

## Edit:

On clicking the Achievements tab i saw a +10 as well. Why then did it show +6 in green for notification?

Comment: Did you click on the achievements dropdown? Did you receive a total of -4 for previous downvotes or deleted content?

Comment: Yes, i checked an it said +10 itself. let me add this as an edit to my answer

Comment: What *preceded* the +10?

Comment: There were two posts removed that you had received +2 for editing.

Comment: @Martijn, there were no other activities from me today.

Comment: @Bill, Why do I loose points if someone delete's their questions?

Comment: You edited posts that weren't really worth keeping around. Nobody should get reputation for that.

Comment: Oh, So all that time for nothing. Thanks a lot, i will be more selective from now on.

Comment: See [New top bar can't math](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210139) and posts in the linked sidebar. It's a "feature", not a bug...